# $1 = \int f(x) \ dx$, by definition, or by Lebesgue's theorem?

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

We have that (in the context of Lebesgue integration)$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^n f(x) \ dx = 1$$
I wish to show that this implies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \ dx = 1$. Is this true *by definition* of the expression on the left, or is this true by monotone convergence: $$1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int 1_{(-\infty,n]}f(x) \ dx = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1_{(-\infty,n]}f(x) \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$$
where MC was invoked at the second equation sign?

EDIT: In above, $f$ is a positive, measurable function.

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: It's a measurable, positive function.

Comment: You may want to include the non-negativity of $f$ in the question -- it's an important detail, espcially when invoking monotone convergence.

Comment: It is true by monotone convergence. I would not say it is true by definition. In particular, it is possible that the limit exists but the Lebesgue integral of over the entire line does not (but not in the nonnegative case).